# Issues finding average of elements

Tags: c, replit

Working with Repl.it and trying to use a function in C to average the elements in a variable length array. My program works fine in every other i/o area other than the average which returns:

The average for that day is: -nan. Any insight on what the issue may be?

The goal is to receive user input as a double(for example, how many pints of blood were taken per hour over a 7 hr period and then use a function call to calculate the average amount for that seven hour period.

New code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
double average(int size, float ary[*]);


int main(void)
{
char dayOne[8], dayTwo[8];
int size;
float ave;

printf("Over how many hours do you want to view donation amounts?: "); 
scanf("%d", &size);
if (size < 7 || size > 7)
  size = 7;
printf("Enter day that you want to see average donation amount for: ");
scanf("%s", dayOne);
{
    float ary[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter amount taken in hour %d:", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &ary[i]);

    }
    ave = average(size, ary);
    printf("\nThe average donated for %s is: %2.1f", dayOne, ave);
 }

 printf("\n\nEnter day that you want to see average donation amount for: ");
 scanf("%s", dayTwo);

if(strcmp(dayOne, dayTwo)== 0)
   printf("\nEnter a different day please: ");

   scanf("%s", dayTwo);

 {
  float ary[size];

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("\nEnter amount taken in hour %d:", i + 1);
    scanf("%f", &ary[i]);
 }
    ave = average(size, ary);
    printf("\nThe average donated for %s is: %2.1f", dayTwo, ave);

}   


return 0;
}

double average(int size, float ary[])
{

double sum = 0;

double ave;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    sum += ary[i];

ave = (double)sum / size;
return ave;
}
```

Comment: We couldn't possibly diagnose the issue without seeing your code. Please edit your post and add your full/representative code in a code block. Also, give sample input/output and expected and actual behavior. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hello @Bwarr, would like to post your full code? So we can solve your problem easily.

Comment: Both of the errors reported in my answer were found simply by compiling with warnings enabled. Enable warnings in your compiler. There is usually some default set of “most” warnings that provides a good selection of useful warnings. Find that setting and enable it. If you state which compiler you are using, people can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
int ary[7];
…
scanf("%f", &ary[i]);
```

`%f` is for scanning a `float`, but `ary[i]` is an `int`. The resulting behavior is not defined.

This is wrong:

```
double size;
…
ave = average(size, ary);
```

Nothing in the “…” assigns a value to `size`, so it has no defined value when `average` is called.

Comment: Thank you. That gives me an idea on where to focus my efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few syntactical and logical changes to be made buddy. As Eric Postpischil has mentioned in his answer, your `size` variable isn't initialized to anything before use. And using `%f` for accepting integers is incorrect too. Along with these, there are a few other glitches which I will list below, with the corresponding fixes. I have also attached the full working code along with the output.

1. **Error:** `size` variable not initialized.

   **Fix:**: Since you have a fixed number of hours, you can either use the `7` directly or through `size`. Hence initialize the variable while declaring it. And just a suggestion buddy, use `int` for `size`. ==>  `int size = 7;`
2. **Error:** Accepting input for array values. The array `ary` is of type `int`, but you have used `%f` which is a format specifier for `float`.

   **Fix:** Use `%d` which is the format specifier for `int` data type. ==> `scanf("%d", &ary[i]);`
3. **Error:** Format specifier used for printing the average value. You have used `%f` again which is for `float` while the variable `ave` for average if of type `double`.

   **Fix:** Use `%lf` which is the format specifier for `double`.  ==> `printf("\nThe average for the 2nd day is: %.3lf", ave);`  The `.3` before `lf` is just to limit the number of decimal points to 3. It is optional.
4. **Error:** You accept the second day and display a message if it is the same as the first day, but the `scanf` for this is out of the `if` loop. hence it prompts the user to input another name of the day regardless of whether the second input day is same as the first or not.

   **Fix:** just move that `scanf` into the `if` loop where you check if that day is same as the previous one.
5. I wouldn't really call this one an error, because it's just an improvement which I find that needs to be done. You accept the second day which should be different from the first with the message that average would be found. But you are not calculating the average for this day. Hence I have included that part in the code.

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
double average(int, int [7]);


    int main(void)
    {
        char dayOne[8], dayTwo[8];
        int size = 7;
        double ave;


        printf("Enter day that you want to see average donation amount for: ");
        scanf("%s", dayOne);

        int ary[7];

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter amount taken in hour %d:", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &ary[i]);

        }
        ave = average(size, ary);
        printf("\nThe average for the 1st day is: %.3lf", ave);


        printf("\n\nEnter day that you want to see average donation amount for:");
        scanf("%s", dayTwo);

        if(strcmp(dayOne, dayTwo)== 0) {
            printf("\nEnter a different day please: ");
            scanf("%s", dayTwo);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter amount taken in hour %d:", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &ary[i]);
        }

        ave = average(size, ary);
        printf("\nThe average for the 2nd day is: %.3lf", ave);

        return 0;
    }

    double average(int size, int ary[7])
    {

        int sum = 0;
        double ave;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum = sum + ary[i];
    }
        ave = sum / size;
        return ave;
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ```
> Enter day that you want to see average donation amount for:  Day1
> Enter amount taken in hour 1: 1
> Enter amount taken in hour 2: 2
> Enter amount taken in hour 3: 3
> Enter amount taken in hour 4: 4
> Enter amount taken in hour 5: 5
> Enter amount taken in hour 6: 6
> Enter amount taken in hour 7: 7
>
> The average for the 1st day is: 4.000
>
> Enter day that you want to see average donation amount for: Day2
> Enter amount taken in hour 1: 8
> Enter amount taken in hour 2: 8
> Enter amount taken in hour 3: 8
> Enter amount taken in hour 4: 8
> Enter amount taken in hour 5: 8
> Enter amount taken in hour 6: 8
> Enter amount taken in hour 7: 8
>
> The average for the 2nd day is: 8.000
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to focus my attentions on the issues Eric highlighted and found the solution. Thank you very much for your input. I'll post my final code and compare it to yours to see where some changes could be made to mine to perhaps make it a bit cleaner if possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. double size;

The size variable has not been set before calling the average function.
ave = average(size, ary);

May be size can be initialized to 0 and incremented in the for loop as given below

```
double size = 0;
double ave;
printf("Enter day that you want to see average donation amount for: ");
scanf("%s", dayOne);
{
int ary[7];

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    printf("Enter amount taken in hour %d:", i + 1);
    scanf("%f", &ary[i]);
    size++;

}
ave = average(size, ary);
printf("\nThe average for the day is: %f", ave);
}
```

2. If the goal is to receive user input as a double, the array used to hold those values should be double.

double ary[7]; 
instead of 
int ary[7];

Comment: I was using an integer value as size of array to store a double value. For instance,  an input of 5.4 for hour 1, 6.2 for hour 2.......and so on but yes, you are correct and that is what my issue was. I also used a variable length array and used an asterisk as the array size in the function definition and simply left it blank in the function definition which worked fine.